# If both Mac OS and Windows use the x86 instruction set, why do we have to recompile for each platform?

Tags: c++11

If both Mac OS and Windows, running on Intel processors, use the x86 instruction set, why can't a program written using only C++11 (no OS Specific libraries, frameworks or API's), run on both without having to recompile for that platform ?

Ultimately the program gets compiled to machine code, so if the instruction set is the same, whats the difference ? What's really going on ?

EDIT: I'm really just talking about a simple "Hello world" program compiled with something like gcc. Not Apps!

EDIT: For example:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hello World!";
        return 0;
    }
```

EDIT: An even simpler program:

```
int main(){
    int j = 2;
    j = j + 3;
}
```

Comment: why close ? Its a legitimate question. If the instruction set is the same, the same set of instructions should run!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a "program" nowadays consists of more than just a blob of binary code. Their file formats are not cross-compatible (PE/COFF vs. ELF vs. Mach-O). It's kind of silly when you think about it, yes, but that's the reality. It wouldn't have to be this way if you could start history over again.

#### Edit:

You may also want to see my longer answer [on SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/247366) (and others').

Comment: Can you explain ? I'm really just talking about a simple hello world program, compiled with gcc...

Comment: @John: Yes, what I'm saying is even if your program is as simple as `int main() { }` it will result in a file that is at least a kilobyte or so, because there is more to the file than just the code that is running. At the bare minimum, before the code itself, the file also contains header information explaining what OSes it's compatible with, where the code actually begins, what address the file is supposed to be mapped to in memory, a checksum, the size of the stack and heap initially required, where the debug info is located, where the location info is located, etc... these all take space.

Comment: A side note to expand on this is that C++ is built on a (set of) C libraries which often contain some OS specific junk too.

Answer (score 2):

Even "Hello, world" needs to generate output. That will either be OS calls, BIOS calls at a somewhat lower level, or, as was common in DOS days for performance reasons, direct output to video via I/O calls or memory mapped video. Any of those methods will be highly specific to the operating system and other design issues. In the example you've listed, iostream hides those details and will be different for each target system.

Comment: I feel thats what my question is about - if iostream is different in each OS, then it makes sense to recompile because its really two different programs. But if there isn't even a header file, then the programs are identical...

Comment: You're changing things here. First example is a real "Hello world" with a header that will make things different. Second example has no visible output or any other useful side-effects, so while it might (assuming that 2 different OSes happen to handle the same executable file format) run, it would be useless - nothing visible, no files changed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is provided by @Mehrdad in their answer: even if the assembly code is the same on all platforms, the way it's "wrapped" into an executable file may differ. Back in the day, there were [COM files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file) in MS-DOS. You could load this file in a memory and then just start executing it from the very beginning.

Eventually we've got read-only memory pages, [.bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss), non-executable read-write memory pages (non-executable for safety reasons), embedded resources (like icons on Windows), and other stuff which the OS should know about *before* running the code in order to properly configure the isolated environment for the newly created process. Of course, there are also shared libraries (which have to be loaded by the OS) and any program which does anything meaningful has to output some result via OS call, e.g. it has to know how to perform system calls.

So, turns out that in multi-process modern OSes executable files should contain a lot of metainformation in addition to the code. That's why we have file formats. They are different on different platforms mainly for historical reasons. Think of it as of PNG vs JPEG - both are compressed rasterized image formats, but they're incompatible, use different algorithms for compression and different storage formats.

> no OS Specific libraries, frameworks or API's

That's not true. As we live in multi-process OS, no process has any kind of direct access to the hardware - be it network card or display. In general, it can only access CPU and memory (in a very limited way).

E.g. when you run your program in terminal, its output should get to the terminal emulator, so it can be displayed in a window, which you can drag across the screen, transparently for your "Hello World". So, OS gets involved anyway.

Even your "hello world" application has to:

1. Load dynamic C++ runtime, which will initialize `cin` object before your `main` starts. Who else will initialize `cin` object and call destructors when `main` ends?
2. When you try to print something, your C++ runtime will eventually have to make a call to the OS. Nowadays, it's typically abstracted away in C standard library (`libc`), which we have to load dynamically even before C++ runtime.
3. That C standard library invokes some x86 instructions which make the system call which "prints" the string on the screen. Note that different OSes and different CPUs (even among x86 family) have different mechanisms and conventions about system calls. Some use interruptions, some use specifically designed `sysenter`/`syscall` instructions (hello from Intel and AMD), some pass arguments in known memory locations, some pass them via registers. Again, that's why this code is abstracted away by the OS's standard library - it typically provides some simple C interface which makes necessary assembly-level magic.

All in all, answering your question: because your program *have to* interact with the OS and different OSes use completely different mechanisms for that.

If your program has no side effects (like your second example), then it is still saved in the "general" format. And, as "general" formats differ between platforms, we should recompile. It's just not worth to invent a common compatible format for simple programs with no side effects, as they are useless.

Comment: @John If the OS, processor and required shared libraries are the same, then program will just run. Did I accidentally say otherwise somewhere?

Comment: Actually PNG vs. JPEG is a bad comparison as PNG is lossless and JPEG is not, so the resulting output when displayed is, at some level, nearly always different starting from the same source image. PNG vs. GIF is a better analogy - same lossless output but different format, compression, etc.

Comment: @manassehkatz I thought about this, but GIF supports animations, so it's not ideal either. And SVN vs EMF sounds too fancy.